# read[command] in bash

Tags: linux, shell

When I read[command] some lines including character `'*'`, it seems that `'*'` will be looked as a wildcard. whether exsits some solutions leting `'*'` just be a `'*'`, please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want any of the special file name characters to be used as wildcards then enter the following in your script before the read.

`set -o noglob`

This will prevent the * ? and [] from having special meaning and treat them as normal characters.

The following example demonstrates the point

```
touch 1 2 3
echo "With wild card expansion"
echo *

echo "Without wild card expansion"
set -o noglob
echo *
```

```
And produces the following results

With wild card expansion
1 2 3 
Without wild card expansion
*
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends how you use the variable: if you quote it, filename expansion will not happen. Example:

```
$ ls
f1  f2  f3
$ read line
*
$ echo "$line"
*
$ echo $line
f1 f2 f3
```

Comment: thanks, i've found the problem using quote for the first point but not the second, which is not about [read]

Answer (score 0):

You can escape it with the escape character: `\*`. This means the `*` will be a literal `*`, not matching one or more characters as the glob pattern.

Comment: what if a line like '\t\abc\o * \abcdefg'